# Ready UI components (controls)

Tags: components, android

I am looking for ready solutions of ready made UI components (or controlls as you may think of). Up to now I have been able to find free GreenDroid and paid DroidUX. Do you know about other ready made solutions for designing apps?

Thanks a lot

Hmyzak

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, there are lots of ready made component available for design purpose in android. you can google it. 
But as my request don't use that component.
Yes, you can use that components but its for the normal application where are no any complex design. but if there are complex design in your application then you can get many trouble during execution of the application.
Hope you got my point.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. What do you mean by "complex design"?

Comment: Complex design means there are many Layout in your application. As like  parent layout is Linear/RelativeLayout and there are many number of layout available in between that layout. At that time if you want to do animation to some specific layout then it may be deficult with that readyMade Component that is used to make design.